# Failed review on first post

Tags: support, review-audits, bounty, disputed-review-audits, first-post-review

I was reviewing question about android and problem with google maps: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/11236645

I failed the review, because I added a comment that users should also post layouts of the activities. And review result showed that the first comment, which couldn't be seen before was exactly that, asking about layout.

Comment: So, even though you left the comment, did you also flag the question to be closed?

Comment: *sigh*, [bounty question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34761952/timeline#history_423215c0-af9d-4787-8134-cd66533f6dac) + [tag:android] tag = upvotes like candy. Bounty questions were supposed to be excluded as audits a while back, I wonder what happened here.

Comment: @BrendanAbel I didn't flag it. The moment that I posted the comment, it said that I failed the review.

Comment: @Brendan because of the score (caused by the bounty) it became a known-good audit, even though it is a  bad question that should be closed.

Comment: Remember, leaving comments or upvoting them whilst reviewing _doesn't actually do anything_.

Comment: @Luke, are you sure about that ? I'm pretty certain that commenting in review does actually leave a comment. Did you mean "Commenting on audits does not do anything" perhaps ?

Comment: @JonasCz It seems that way. At least the last time I tried to action comments during reviewing (a few years ago) nothing ever happened on the live question page. The more you know!

Comment: @Luke My comment wasn't added to live question page. But the moment that I posted the comment I failed the review.